# Page and token management in a pure JavaScript app

Tags: javascript, jwt, redirect

I´m trying to build a pure JavaScript app, This app does call to an API, and that API return a token which I will save in a cookie (any advice about it?).

I have many doubts, the most important are the following,

How should I make the redirect stuff between pages, and how I prevent that someone access to my page, I want to do something like if there is not cookie (token) and the token is invalid (I will check the token before show the page), redirect to login, if is all correct, show the home page for example

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your token in a cookie you should start page load with an API call that verifies session. If API returns false simply redirect user to login page, otherwise execute rest of your javascript. I assume your sensitive data will come from subsequent API calls that should also verify the token.

You probably understand that you can't protect the static content using this method since anyone can add breakpoints on browsers and modify the JS code to their preferences (as in remove the forced redirect), so your focus should be on loading everything you want to be *hidden* through ajax API calls that are secured with token.